# The service denied use of the directions service by this application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I would like to use this library to use google map as a router.

https://github.com/poulpix/PXGoogleDirections

my api key:

```
AIzaSyAHQPNUQuSYLUsa3JxVxTyUH_Lab-7EPxc
```

I got this api key from this link:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

[image]

my codes:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initialValues()

    let directionsAPI = PXGoogleDirections(apiKey: "AIzaSyAHQPNUQuSYLUsa3JxVxTyUH_Lab-7EPxc",
                            from: PXLocation.coordinateLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.331690, -122.030762)),
                                           to: PXLocation.specificLocation("Googleplex", "Mountain View", "United States"))


    directionsAPI.calculateDirections({ response in
        switch response {
        case let .error(_, error):
            // Oops, something bad happened, see the error object for more information
            print("errorrrr \(error)")
            break
        case let .success(request, routes):
            // Do your work with the routes object array here
            print("ok map")
            break
        }
    })

}
```

my error:

```
errorrrr Error Domain=PXGoogleDirectionsErrorDomain Code=6 "The service denied use of the directions service by this application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The service denied use of the directions service by this application}
```

another question,if my key works fine, where will map show? I think it need to a empty `view`.

Comment: Are you sure your bundle ID matches what is set in your google developer account?

Comment: yes. it is `com.ashidgroup.kashanmap`

Comment: I'm testing my project on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

[image]You need to enable the place api as well.

steps:- go to console->credential->library->place library->enabled.